# Functors such that $Hom(FX,GY)=Hom(GX,FY)$?

Tags: category-theory

Let $F,G:\mathcal{C}\to \mathcal{D}$ be functors between two (small) categories. Suppose further that there are natural bijections (in objects $X$ and $Y$ of $\mathcal{C}$)
$$ Hom_\mathcal{D}(FX,GY)\cong Hom_\mathcal{D}(GX,FY)$$
Is there a name for such functors? Is there a way to phrase this as an adjunction? A reference would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you have any motivating examples?

Comment: @varkor The example that I have in mind would take pretty long to define... very roughly $F$ is a certain "categorified comultiplication" from $\mathcal{C}$ to $\mathcal{C}^{\otimes 2}$ and $G$ is something like an inclusion (rather a pullback...) of the first copy of $\mathcal{C}$ into $\mathcal{C}^{\otimes 2}$. This probably won't help...